# How to use Retrofit2 to parse json into class with subclass(es)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, retrofit2

How to convert given json response

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Doe",
    "location" : {
        "name" : "Paris",
        "desc" : "Welcome to Paris"
    }
}
```

into

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    String surname;
    Location location;  // new Location(String name, String desc)
}
```

It's all about nested `Location` class that is inside `Person` class

Comment: use this site to generate the Json class according to the json Response http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Expose` or `@SerializedName` annotation like

```
class Person
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("surname")
    String surname;

    @SerializedName("location")
    Location location;  // new Location(String name, String desc)
}
```

and `Location` class like

```
 class Location
    {
        @SerializedName("name")
        String name;

        @SerializedName("desc")
        String desc;
   }
```

Add getter and setter method for accessing data

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of Gson + Retrofit.

First of all use the annotation `@SerializedName("yourFieldName")` that Retrofit provides in the fields of your model class.

Init your Gson configuration with a `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Person> itemFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
        .of(Person.class) // The field that defines the type
        .registerSubtype(Location.class, "location")
        .registerSubtype(YourSubclass.class) // if the flag equals the class name, you can skip the second parameter.

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(itemFactory)
        .create();
```

Then you init Retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
builder.baseUrl(BASE_URL);
builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

Comment: Overcomplicated compared to first response, but still useful

Comment: This method makes the whole system dynamic. It lets you instantiate different objects autmatically with an instance of Retrofit. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

First get an API and get its JSON output by Advance REST Client which is a Chrome Extension. Now put that output to [JSON to POJO converter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
and you'll get your POJO Classes. Paste them to your project. Make an interface`

```
/**
 * Get Data
 *
 * @param body Holds the JSON payloads
 * @return Formatted data
 */
@POST("JobSpotAPI/getUserInterviewSchedule")
Call<POJOClass> getData(@Body JsonObject body);
```

and setup a Client

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Create a Recycler view setup its adapter and all. Just add a few new methods like-

```
 public void updateAnswers(List<Item> items) {
    mItems = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private Item getItem(int adapterPosition) {
    return mItems.get(adapterPosition);
}
```

Setup Utility class to call the interface.

```
public class ApiUtils {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://base_url/";

public static Interface_name methodName() {
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(Interface_name.class);
}}
```

Declare the Interface in your Activity

```
Interface_name obj = ApiUtils.methodName();
```

If you have some payloads then attach them to you request. Before that you need a JSON string to pass to API request. To make a JSON Payload.

```
  private JsonObject makeJsonObjectPayload() {
    JsonObject requestBean = new JsonObject();
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    requestBean.addProperty("key", value);
    return requestBean;
```

Pass the API request

```
obj.getData(makeJsonObjectPayload()).enqueue(new Callback<POJOClass>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<POJOClass> call, Response<POJOClass> response) {

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            mAdapter.updateAnswers(response.body().getItems());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
        }else {
            int statusCode  = response.code();
            // handle request errors depending on status code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UserDataPOJOClass> call, Throwable t) {
        //showErrorMessage();
        Log.d("API ERROR",""+t.getMessage());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

    }
});
```